# Having trouble accessing table elements

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test my table but I can't seem the access the table headers? I am testing that 6 exist as seen in the logs below.

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "th"

Here are the accessible roles:
```

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

import Table from "../Table/Table"

describe('Table', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        render(<Table />)
    })

    it('should render headers', () => {
        screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL()
        expect(screen.getAllByRole('th')).toHaveLength(6)
    })
})
```

```
          <table class="sc-dkrFOg eudlDK">
            <thead class="sc-iBYQkv fBmNxW">
              <tr class="sc-hLBbgP imKlCt">
                <th class="sc-eDvSVe jtchdi">
                  ID
                </th>
                <th class="sc-eDvSVe jtchdi">
                  NAME
                </th>
                <th class="sc-eDvSVe jtchdi">
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="sc-gKPRtg"/>
          </table>
```

I have tried reading various docs online.

Comment: `getAllByRole('th')` "th" is not a role. that is why you could not access. some html elemenets an implicit role, and `th`'s role is "columnheader"

Answer (score 0):

This works. I am accessing via columnheader.

```
it('shoulda colum with id', () => {
    expect(screen.getByRole('columnheader', { name: /id/i })).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```